# Textbook suggestion for studying martingales

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

I've been studying probability from Davar Khoshnevisan's [graduate textbook](http://books.google.com.tr/books?id=KDj49iyN6GcC&printsec=frontcover&hl=tr&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) since the beginning of the semester. A month ago, I came to the chapter of "Martingales". Since it's my first encounter with martingales, I found it a little confusing and hard to grasp. I totally understand the definitions and the theorems, but I feel like I am not seeing the big picture of it. I mean I need to digest it a little more.
In such times, reading the same concept from different textbook or from a different perspective of view may help you to complete some missing pieces. My question is: Can you please suggest me a textbook or an article about martingales to read to supplement my textbook?

Comment: i have to say other than wikipedia

Comment: rosenthal's A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what kind of book you are looking but I can suggest you one of the good ones that i like,  David Williams- Probability with Martingales , Olav Kallenberg - Foundations of Modern Probability, Patrick Billingley - Probability  and Measure,and Varadhan's lecture notes.. Good luck.

Comment: Oh my God @user5656 what would i do without you...I wish luck you too. I think we all gonna need it...

Comment: what about rosenthal's A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory?