# What are some good books about martingales?

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, martingales

I'm looking for suggestions for well written books dealing with martingale theory, not necessarily exclusively. I'm also looking for a nice compilation of problems, preferably with answers, on this topic.

EDIT: I'm particularly interested in discrete time martingales.

Comment: Schilling, maybe.

Comment: Williams: Probability with Martingales

Comment: i've just asked a similar [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641302/textbook-suggestion-for-studying-martingales) and got zero respond. So +1 from me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[René Schilling: Measures, Integrals and Martingales](http://www.motapa.de/measures_integrals_and_martingales/index.html)

The solution manual is not contained in the book, but available on the web page.